# How to order rows in MySQL when using in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using this query to select rows in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (5,2,3,1,4);
```

Now by default the rows will be ordered by their `id`: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Is there any way that I can order rows as they are in the query, so the order should be: `5, 2, 3, 1, 4` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL's [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE `id` IN (5,2,3,1,4)
 ORDER BY FIELD(`id`, 5,2,3,1,4)
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` statement to customize the sort

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  id IN ( 5, 2, 3, 1, 4 )
ORDER  BY CASE id
            WHEN 5 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 2
            WHEN 3 THEN 3
            WHEN 1 THEN 4
            WHEN 4 THEN 5
            ELSE 6
          END
```